# Excel VBA: Finding an Object in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an Excel VBA function. Users enter 2 parameters and the function checks if the first is in the second, returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I have gotten it to work as a subroutine but not a function. What am I missing?

This is probably pretty basic, but it has been giving me some issues.

Thanks!

**I realize that I could use an array instead of a collection, but I'd prefer it like this if possible

EDIT: To describe the problem in a little more detail: I am looking to determine if the value in `input_cell` is found in the `list` range, not if `input_cell` is located in the `list` range.

When I enter the two values, it returns a `#VALUE!` error

```
Function INRANGE(input_cell As Range, list As Range) As Boolean

Dim coll As New Collection

'*******Add items to coll********'

'Find size of collection
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = list.Rows.Count
'Cells(Rows.Count, input_cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

'Add rows to collection
Dim i As Integer
For i = list.Row To LastRow
    coll.Add Cells(i, list.Column).Value
    Next i

'*******Search collection********'

Dim Current_Cell As Variant

Dim isInList As Boolean
isInList = False

Dim k As Integer 'Count of loop through list

For k = list.Row To LastRow
    If input_cell = coll(k) Then
        isInList = True

    End If

    Next k

INRANGE = isInList

End Function
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the function from within the function itself. You've also declared two range parameters and are not supplying them. You should not tell the function to equal false. You need to supply the parameters to the function to receive the boolean value back from it (as you've declared).

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in `Intersect` function, which returns `TRUE/FALSE` based on the intersection of two ranges. Based on your post, I think the `Intersect` would accomplish what you need in a single line of code and more efficiently.

Comment: Are you trying to determine if input_cell is inside the list (e.g. C2 is inside C1:C10) or are you trying to determine if the value in input_cell is found in the list (e.g. 5 is inside {3, 2, 6, 7, 5, 10, 11}

Comment: Isn't this basically just a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)?  Why are you writing a brand new UDF when a built in function already does this for you?

Comment: It seems to work fine here.  Of course, you have only provided the function code leading us to guess at the data setup and what you mean by not working.  Please read HELP for [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  One possibility is that list.row is not = 1 so you are never looking at the first part of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

While collections aren't my strong suit I believe what you have missed is the adding the key  to the collection. The following edit should work:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = list.Row To LastRow
    coll.Add Cells(i, list.Column).Value, Cells(i, list.Column).Value
    Next i
```

Comment: and the way your code is set up, the data needs to start in row 1 (no headers) for it to work

Comment: The method he is using does not require a key for the collection.  He is checking the value of the collection item.

Comment: Doesn't the test 'If input_cell = coll(k)' check the key though?

Comment: No, since it is a Integer, it checks the Index.  A collection key must be a string.

Comment: Gotcha. So code provided in the question works fine, its just that it needs to be in row 1.

Comment: And tigeravatar is correct in saying that a simple countif function would be much easier than a UDF

Comment: Yes to both.  Or he could index through the collection adjusting `k` for `list.row`  eg `col(k-list.row+1)`

Comment: Would you explain why it needs to be in row 1?

Comment: @Jon You start iterating through the collection at `list.row`.  So if `list.row` = 3, you will miss `collection(1)` and `collection(2)`